# SQLAlchemy - Modifying Many-to-Many Relationships Between Existing Entities

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two entities with a many to many relationship, defined like so:

```
teacher_student = Table('teacher_student', Base.metadata,
   Column('teacher_id', Integer, ForeignKey('teacher.id')),
   Column('student_id', Integer, ForeignKey('student.id')))

class Teacher(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teacher'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    students = relationship('Student', secondary=teacher_student, 
                            back_populates="teachers")

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'student'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    teachers = relationship('Teacher', secondary=teacher_student, 
                            back_populates="students")
```

I have a collection of "teachers" and "students" persisted, and I would like to update the relationships between them. For example, I want to lookup an existing teacher and then remove and add some existing students (without actually affecting the `student` table). I can't figure out how to do this without SQL alchemy attempting to perform an insert for added students (which results in an integrity exception).

Here is what I am attempting:

```
with session() as session:
    teacher = session.query(Teacher)\
                     .filter_by(id=1)\
                     .first()

    teacher.students.append(Student(id=1))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Look the student up as well, instead of creating a new instance. Where's the removal part?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I was hoping I could avoid the extra lookup, but ok I'll try that. Removal works as expected (i.e. by dropping item from list).